# how to fix confliction of Custom Option is required yes with bundle item?

Tags: magento-1.9, custom-options, bundled-product

how to fix confliction of Custom Option is required yes with bundle item?

In Bundle Product grid have displayed all product as bundle items but not save some product because that product has the custom option is required field as YES.